# Conditional Column in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have an orders table which looks like this:

```
Customer    Date       Value
C1          2019-01-12     2
C2          2019-01-12     3
C3          2019-01-12    45
C4          2019-01-12    12
C1          2019-01-14     1
C3          2019-01-14     6
C1          2019-01-25     5
```

In this table, I want to add a column "Rewards", which returns yes if a customer has a transaction in the last 7 days and "no" if he has no transactions in the last 7 days.

Here's the desired output:

```
Customer  Date        Value Rewards
C1        2019-01-12      2 No
C2        2019-01-12      3 No
C3        2019-01-12     45 No
C4        2019-01-12     12 No
C1        2019-01-14      1 Yes
C3        2019-01-14      6 Yes
C1        2019-01-25      5 No
```

I'm new to SQL and I'm not even sure how to approach this problem. Any help is appreciated.

For each transaction(i.e. each row), I want to add a check if the user has done any transactions in the last 7 days, Last 7 days at the time of the transaction (if the transaction is done of Jan14, I will check if there are any transactions from Jan7 to jan14.

Comment: A few things are unclear. Is this table the transactions table? Also, as in the above question, output should be having only entry per customer

Comment: For each transaction(i.e. each row), I want to add a check if the user has done any transactions in the last 7 days, Last 7 days at the time of the transaction (if the transaction is done of Jan14, I will check if there are any transactions from Jan7 to jan14

Comment: At all - I understand it as: "The customer gets a reward for a transaction, if there has already been a transaction within last 7 days". `01-14` has `yes` because `01-12` is within 7 days.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel You are correct

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Thanks for clearing that up

Comment: @Leo Can a customer have two transactions in a single day?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel: No...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a case for an EXISTS subquery.

```
select Customer, Date, Value,
  case when exists (
    select *
    from transactions t1
    where t1.Customer = t.Customer
      and t1.Date >= t.Date - interval 7 day
      and t1.Date <  t.Date
  ) then 'Yes' else 'No' end as Rewards
from transactions t;
```

Now you can't just convert it to an UPDATE statement - The engine would complain about something like "cannot SELECT and UPDATE from the same table". So you will need to wrap the select statement into a subquery and join it with the same table for update:

```
update transactions u
join (
  select Customer, Date, Value,
    case when exists (
      select *
      from transactions t1
      where t1.Customer = t.Customer
        and t1.Date >= t.Date - interval 7 day
        and t1.Date <  t.Date
    ) then 'Yes' else 'No' end as Rewards
  from transactions t
) s using (Customer, Date)
set u.Rewards = s.Rewards;
```

Demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eJcwgzwS7QjJcJ5MFWaz8L/0

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(transaction_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,customer CHAR(2) NOT NULL
,date DATE NOT NULL
,value INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table (customer,date,value) VALUES
('C1','2019-01-12', 2),
('C2','2019-01-12', 3),
('C3','2019-01-12',45),
('C4','2019-01-12',12),
('C1','2019-01-14', 1),
('C3','2019-01-14', 6),
('C1','2019-01-25', 5);

SELECT a.transaction_id
     , a.customer
     , a.date
     , a.value
     , COALESCE(a.date BETWEEN b.date AND b.date + INTERVAL 7 DAY,0) reward
  FROM 
     ( SELECT x.*
            , MAX(y.transaction_id) prev 
         FROM my_table x 
         LEFT 
         JOIN my_table y 
           ON y.customer = x.customer 
          AND y.transaction_id < x.transaction_id 
        GROUP 
           BY x.transaction_id
     ) a
  LEFT
  JOIN my_table b
    ON b.transaction_id = a.prev;

+----------------+----------+------------+-------+--------+
| transaction_id | customer | date       | value | reward |
+----------------+----------+------------+-------+--------+
|              1 | C1       | 2019-01-12 |     2 |      0 |
|              2 | C2       | 2019-01-12 |     3 |      0 |
|              3 | C3       | 2019-01-12 |    45 |      0 |
|              4 | C4       | 2019-01-12 |    12 |      0 |
|              5 | C1       | 2019-01-14 |     1 |      1 |
|              6 | C3       | 2019-01-14 |     6 |      1 |
|              7 | C1       | 2019-01-25 |     5 |      0 |
+----------------+----------+------------+-------+--------+
```

Comment: Change last row from `2019-01-25` to `2019-01-20` :-)

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Coffee injected